# Create folder outside public_html to upload files

Tags: php

I creating script and I need to let users upload files (images) . and for security reasons I want to make file folder outside `public_html`.

But my problem is maybe my potential customers may have different folders structure in their servers.

So my question is : There is a way in php to go back one folder before `public_html` ?

Another possible case if my client put script file in directory like that `public_html/demo/` , so in that case I need to go  2 folders back.

I try to use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` but it give the public server directory.

any help or suggestion will be helpfull. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the php user has the permission to do so, you should be able to include/write files to a directory using a relative path for example:

```
include("../test.php");
```

Likewise if you had a directory which was writable by the php user you should be able to create files in that directory also using a relative path:

```
$ cat test1.php
<?php

    $file = fopen("../test.php", "w");
    fwrite($file,  "Hello World. Testing!\n");
    fclose($file);
    include("../test.php");


$ php test1.php
Hello World. Testing!
```